# How to enable data binding in KnockoutJS using the ASP.NET MVC 3 "Razor" View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement [this Knockout example](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) using ASP MVC 3's "Razor" view engine.

The first topic covers simple data binding of a C# array using the standard ASP view engine. I am trying the sample example using "Razor", and this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>; 
</script>
```

results in an empty variable for *initialData*.

I also tried this:

```
@{
    string data = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}
```

And then specified the initialData like this:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(data);
```

This populates *initialData* with the dataset, but binding does not work.

I'm just trying to databind this set in order to display a count of the ideas, as in the example:

```
<p>You have asked for <span data-bind="text: gifts().length">&nbsp;</span> gift(s)</p>
```

Why isn't data binding working in this instance?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way in MVC3 is to do:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Comment: Thanks, @RP, but it doesn't work for me. I have this: 

<p>You have asked for <span data-bind="text: gifts().length">&nbsp;</span> gift(s).</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    var viewModel = {
        gifts: ko.ObservableArray(initialData)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>                                                                The bindings don't show up for me.

Comment: Can you do a "view source" in your browser and see how initialData looks in the markup?  I have a copy of the gift editor sample that works with this code.  Did you change anything else?  Thanks.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. initialData is just a regular JSON array populated with the correct data. I can throw up an alert box with the correct count, but the ko databinding isn't working. It's super frustrating because the live examples are superb.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?  Are you referencing Knockout and jQuery templates?  Sounds like initialData looks fine.

Comment: Sadly, no JavaScript errors. Yep, I have references to jQuery.templ.js and knockout.js. initialData looks great, but in Firebug gifts says "undefined" in my view model. It's defined as var viewModel = {
        gifts: ko.observableArray(initialData)
    };. Is that right, or should it be just observable? Neither works. Is your sample posted someplace? I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can take a look at this: http://db.tt/5VYfoWz and try to reconcile it with yours.

Comment: Just FYI, my sample was breaking because I used the latest jQuery (1.5.1), jQuery template, and Knockout libs. I replaced all of that with @RP's example libs and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this same problem, and discovered that it was my own stupidity that caused the issue (which it so often is).  I forgot to wait until the DOM loaded to call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` - so simply using:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
```

So the whole script as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var initialData = @Html.Raw( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
var viewModel = {
    gifts: ko.observableArray(initialData)
};

$(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
</script>
```

This worked with knockout-1.2.1.js and jquery-1.5.1.js

Comment: You just helped me solve a problem I was banging my head against for the last 2 days. Thank you.