# Knockout JS, MVC 3 and View Model Server Side Data as JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

So I have a problem...I am separating concerns in my web app: HTML in razor pages and JS in js files.  My problem lies in the fact that I want to use data from my controller passed down in the view model from the server as the options of a select list.  The problem lies in the fact that I have separated my js from my HTML and I can't access Razor inside the js files.

I have a list of items coming down into my view model...

`public List Stuffs { get; set; }`

I json encode it server side and make sure to take care of circular refrences, so it looks like this

`[{"id":1,"name":"blah"},{"id":2,"name":"blah2"},{"id":3,"name":"blah3"},{"id":4,"name":"blah4"}]`

The problem is, I want to keep my separation of concerns, so how do I get that array into my js file so I can bind it to a select list using knockout?  I definitely don't want to do another round trip to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable data binding in KnockoutJS using the ASP.NET MVC 3 "Razor" View Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873636/how-to-enable-data-binding-in-knockoutjs-using-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-en)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I think that's only half his question. He wants some way for the javascript to remain seperate from the Razor. That answer only uses Razor.

Comment: @Tyrsius Well there are only three possible answers, embed Javascript in a Razor view, and wire it up on load (as in the answer I linked which is the same as your answer on this question) or AJAX the request after page load, or have a controller that returns models as JS file includes (terrible, might as well be #2
).

Comment: @ErikPhilips The answer you linked is not the same as my answer. It does not show how to keep the javascript's use of the Razor generated JSON in a seperate file. *This is an important difference*.

Comment: @Tyrsius ah yes I see, you are right. The transition from the answer I provided to your answer, for me, was so basic I over looked it.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering quickly.  I don't think there is a way to do this and follow the strict model of keeping concerns separated other than making an ajax call to the server following page load.

Comment: @jsteve I don't think that's a good idea. Even if you consider this to break the model, which I would ask you to reconsider, you should still recognize that a REAL difference in performance from an extra ajax request is a *worse option* than creating a loose coupling and "breaking" your strict model. Serializing your model with razor is the method advocated by the Knockout creators, as evidenced in Erik's link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Javascript file contain a view model in the form of an instantiable function, e.g. something like:

```
function MasterVM(data)
```

or an object literal, e.g.

```
var masterVM = { ...
```

? I tend to go for instantiable view models (partly because they chain down through a hierarchy of view models using the mapping plugin - the top level one builds its children) and that being the case I think it's nice for the Razor view to instantiate the view model with the JSON rendered from the MVC view model, e.g.:

```
var masterVM = new MasterVM(@(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ProductViewModel))));
```

Or even have the Knockout view model "owned" by a revealing module and initialise it like:

```
productModule.init(@(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ProductViewModel))));
```

Then productModule is also responsible for other things like mediating between your view model(s) and the server, watching for dirty state, etc.

Also, doing another round trip to the server is not necessarily bad if you are sourcing a massive set of reusable options which you'd like the browser to cache. If you are, you might want to have an MVC controller which emits a big object literal containing all of your commonly used options, which you can then use as the "options" property across multiple selects. But if your options are specific to the particular view model, then I guess they have to be part of your view model.

Comment: Thanks Tom...this is exactly what I did last night!

Answer (score 2):

So lets say you have some view that looks like this:

```
<div> (Some stuff) </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = //Your JSON
<script>
```

And then in your javascript (which you have linked below your view, so that it loads after it), you have something like this:

```
var data = initialData || {} //Or some other default value, in case initialData wasn't set
```

This will load in the `initialData` if it was set, or use nothing (or a default your define) if it wasn't. Loosely coupled.

Of course, more complex data will require you to standardize the strucure, but this is essentially one method that allows you to pull in data from the razor generated View without tightly coupling it to your javascript file.