# Does System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize do something that Json.Encode doesn't?

Tags: json, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

Preface: This is a derivative question of the following questions:

1. [Best practice on passing Mvc Model to KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628938/best-practice-on-passing-mvc-model-to-knockoutjs)
2. [How to enable data binding in KnockoutJS using the ASP.NET MVC 3 "Razor" View Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873636/how-to-enable-data-binding-in-knockoutjs-using-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-en)

---

When passing my MVC view model to KnockoutJS, I was accustomed to using the [following syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5875129/109941):

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

But lately, I've been seeing people use the [following syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290692/109941):

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw( new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
```

---

My Question:

- Does `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize` do something that `Json.Encode` doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's is the other way around: `Json.Encode(Model)` does more then a plain `JavaScriptSerializer`:

Internally the `Json.Encode` also uses the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` but it registers an additional converter called `DynamicJavaScriptConverter`.

Where the `DynamicJavaScriptConverter` is a

> Converter that knows how to get the member values from a dynamic object.

You can check the `Json.Encode` [source online](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/bfa28d1ddbca#src/System.Web.Helpers/Json.cs):

```
public static class Json
{
    private static readonly JavaScriptSerializer _serializer = CreateSerializer();

    public static string Encode(object value)
    {
        // Serialize our dynamic array type as an array
        DynamicJsonArray jsonArray = value as DynamicJsonArray;
        if (jsonArray != null)
        {
            return _serializer.Serialize((object[])jsonArray);
        }

        return _serializer.Serialize(value);
    }       

    private static JavaScriptSerializer CreateSerializer()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJavaScriptConverter() });
        return serializer;
    }

    //...
}
```

So with the using of `Json.Encode` you get some additional support for handling `dynamic` objects but if you don't need it you can use a "vanilia" `JavaScriptSerializer` instead.